# How to convert json array to javascript array using specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i want to convert a json array (string) to javascript array using just some specific values. The json array is :

```
[{"id":47,"libelle":"famille de test"},{"id":1,"libelle":"GEOLOCALISATION"},{"id":4,"libelle":"OUTILS"},{"id":2,"libelle":"PROPRETE"},{"id":3,"libelle":"URGENCE"}]
```

and i want to get something like this ["famille de test", "GEOLOCALISATION", ...] using just libelle values.
I tried to use $.map but didn't work out.

Comment: This didn't work..? `var result = objArray.map(function(a) {return a.libelle;});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map implementation should work:

```
var jsonStr = '[{"id":47,"libelle":"famille de test"},{"id":1,"libelle":"GEOLOCALISATION"},{"id":4,"libelle":"OUTILS"},{"id":2,"libelle":"PROPRETE"},{"id":3,"libelle":"URGENCE"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var libelle = arr.map(function(x) { return x.libelle; });
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted!! Thank you sir. :)

Comment: No problem! If that worked for you could you accept? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you must turn your JSON string into a JavaScript Array by using `JSON.parse(yourJSONString)`. After that, it is a simple JavaScript array and you can use the map method you tried